# What does Task Inflation mean in TPL?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I've been reading [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/1615555D-287C-4159-8491-8E5644C43CBA/TPL%20Performance%20Improvements%20in%20.Net%204.5.pdf) blog post and accompanying pdf document about the performance improvements in TPL for version 4.5 .Net.

The pdf document has a list of instances when it can happen, but I wanted a more precise definition of the term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked document lists what can cause this, but it's effectively when the `Task` class is forced to internally allocate other memory, "inflating" it's size.  Certain use cases cause the `Task` class to allocate an internal `ContingentProperties` class and store a reference within the task, which is referred to as "inflation" in that document.

The normal use case for `Task` will avoid allocating the extra internal class to store these properties, which causes it to stay smaller in overall size most of the time.